# Difficult kind of Hierachical Data in Relational Database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have "components" which can be assembled in different ways into a "system". I want my database to hold all these "components", their type specific data and define how they are connected to each other to form a "system".

The systems are typically gearboxes and they can have rather complex branched designs. Let's start with an easy example:

[image]

This system is built up out of Masses (horizontal lines) and Stiffnesses (vertical lines). Gears and clutches are types of masses and come in pairs. Colors represent different branch speeds due to gear ratios. Here's a (bad) example of how I could store everything from this particular illustration:

```
 ID | Type      | Clutch | Ends    | DrivenBy  | NoOfTeeth| Mass | Stiffness
--- | ----      | ------ | ----    | --------- | -------- | ---- | ---------
 1  | Mass      |        | Input1  |           |          | 5    | 
 2  | Stiffness |        |         |           |          |      | 15
 3  | Mass      | 1.1    |         |           |          | 2    |
 4  | Mass      | 1.2    |         |           |          | 3    |
 5  | Stiffness |        |         |           |          |      | 20
 6  | Gear      |        |         |           | 10       | 4    |
 7  | Stiffness |        |         |           |          |      | 30
 8  | Gear      |        |         |           | 4        | 5    |
 9  | Gear      |        |         | 8         | 7        | 2    |
 10 | Stiffness |        |         |           |          |      | 40
 11 | Mass      |        |         |           |          | 4    |
 12 | Stiffness |        | Output1 |           |          |      | 10
 13 | Gear      |        |         | 6         | 5        | 4    |
 14 | Stiffness |        |         |           |          |      | 20
 15 | Mass      | 2.1    |         |           |          | 4    |
 16 | Mass      | 2.2    |         |           |          | 3
 17 | Stiffness |        |         |           |          |      | 30
 18 | Mass      |        | Output2 |           |          | 2    |
```

Obviously, this is not a very good way to store the data. This design pattern resembles somewhat of a "Repeated attributes" since each component type has a different attribute to be filled. I could create a table for each type of component, but things become more complex when looking at other examples, such as this 2-stage gearbox:

[image]

There are also examples with more than 1 input and several outputs, but I can't post more links due to low reputation.

Eitherway, you will see that the usual hierarchical data storage doesn't apply here because the data is not purely "tree-shaped" where everything branches off from 1 main branch.

I think that even though I could store data in the above mentioned way, I will get huge difficulties when it comes to the programming stage.

To add to the complexity, these gearboxes are actually sub-systems to a much bigger system.

**So, any suggestions on a good way to store this type of data?***

Comment: In your first diagram, are there 3 gearboxes or only 1?

Comment: There's 1 gearbox but there are 2 pairs of gears, 4 gearwheels in total. The other parts in the illustration are clutches and shafts.

Comment: What do the 3 colors mean?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' From the Question: Colors represent different branch speeds due to gear ratios. To explain further, they could be seen as "branches".

Comment: Well, duh. Need more tea.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a possible way of doing it?

[image]

Here you will see that there is a "main" table called GearboxBranch, keeping track of all elements in the gearbox, giving them an id and to identify in which branch the element exists.

Then for the elements themselves, masses are defined in their dedicated table, so are stiffnesses. Gears and Clutches (which are types of masses) are then defined in their perspective tables. A recursive relationship is existing in the gear table, since one gear has to be driven by at least one other gear.

Furthermore, the table with Shaft Ends defines which of the elements in the gearbox are input or output and what number they have.

I can't seem to see any problems with this method, but I'm a little unsure how to get data out of the database. There will be considerable coding involved I'm afraid.